# Java: How to return the node the breaks a binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Working on a method that is supposed to return the node that breaks a binary search tree, or null if none of them do. A few of the test cases pass but some of them are failing and I'm not sure why.
Here's my code so far:

```
public static Node checkBSTValidity(Node rootNode) {
    // Your code here (remove the placeholder line below)
    if (rootNode == null) {
       return null;
    }
    
    // Check if left child node is greater than root node
    if (rootNode.left != null && maxValue(rootNode.left) >= rootNode.key) {
       Node node = new Node(maxValue(rootNode.left));
       return node;
    }
    
    // Check if right child node is less than root node
    if (rootNode.right != null && minValue(rootNode.right) <= rootNode.key) {
       Node node = new Node(minValue(rootNode.right));
       return node;
    }
    
    
    Node leftResult = checkBSTValidity(rootNode.left);
    
    if (leftResult != null) {
       return leftResult;
    }
    
    return checkBSTValidity(rootNode.right);
    
}
```

After submitting the code above, it says: Invalid tree with left/right child linking to ancestor, and my program produces no output. It also says: Invalid tree with left child's key greater than parent's key doesn't return the correct node. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: For the challenge it says to implement checkBSTValidity() that takes the tree's root node as a parameter and returns the node that is violating tree. A violating node will be one of three things:

1. A node in the left subtree of an ancestor with a lesser key
2. A node in the right subtree of an ancestor with a greater key
3. A node with the left or right field referencing an ancestor

Comment: Your code is never returning a node from the tree. It returns a newly constructed node. This is not what is expected.

Comment: When two nodes have values that are not in the expected BST order, then which of the two nodes are the one to return? Can you quote the code challenge literally?

Comment: You don't need maxValue or minValue methods. Just keep checking the left and right nodes at each node for BST property and recurse. And your code probably should return rootNode instead of rootNode.left or rootNode.right if the BST property is broken.

Comment: @SomeDude, how do you know they *"probably should return rootNode instead of rooNode.left or rootNode.right"*? Do you have access to the original code challenge where this is specified?

Comment: @trincot I don't know the code challenge. It is my guess that it should return rootNode because you don't know whether it is left or right that breaks the property , it could be both in which case we don't know what to return. And that could be one of the reasons why OP's code is returning so many incorrect values (it is inefficient nonetheless and incorrect too as it returns new Node)

Comment: Well, yes the new Node is the main issue, which I raised at the first comment here, but the argument that there could be more violations doesn't really work, as there may be other locations in the tree that have violations too. The point is that even when there is only a single violation there are still two nodes involved, and it is not specified which one to return.

Comment: For the challenge it says to implement checkBSTValidity() that takes the tree's root node as a parameter and returns the node that violating node. A violating node will be one of three things:
A node in the left subtree of an ancestor with a lesser key
A node in the right subtree of an ancestor with a greater key
A node with the left or right field referencing an ancestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that your function is creating a new Node instance and returns that, while the task is to return a node that already exists in the tree.

But in comments you also mention that the function should check whether a child node is the same node reference as one of its ancestors. There is no provision for that in your code. I would suggest to use a HashSet for that purpose, to which you can add a node each time you recur to one of the sub trees.

Finally, it is not efficient to call `minValue` and `maxValue` on every node, as this way you'll visit nodes multiple times, giving the whole process a time complexity of O(log), while this can be done with O() time complexity.

One idea is to pass to the recursive call a "window" that must contain all values in the subtree. Initially this window is unbounded. If the data type for the keys is `int`, we could use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as boundaries of the window.

Here is how it could be coded:

```
private static Node checkBSTValidity(Node rootNode, int low, int high,
                                     HashSet<Node> ancestors) {
    if (rootNode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // Track each ancestor as we traverse down the tree
    ancestors.add(rootNode);
    // Any violation?
    if (rootNode.key < low || rootNode.key > high 
            || ancestors.contains(rootNode.left) 
            || ancestors.contains(rootNode.right)) {
        return rootNode;
    }
    // Check the sub trees
    Node node = checkBSTValidity(rootNode.left, low, rootNode.key, ancestors);
    if (node == null) {
        node = checkBSTValidity(rootNode.right, rootNode.key, high, ancestors);
    }
    ancestors.remove(rootNode); // Backtrack
    return node;
}

public static Node checkBSTValidity(Node rootNode) {
    HashSet<Node> ancestors = new HashSet<>();
    return checkBSTValidity(rootNode, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                            ancestors);
}
```

To collect all ancestors in a set may seem overkill, but it is needed to track all of them in case duplicate keys are allowed in the tree. We could have a path down the tree with nodes that all have the same keys, and where a child is a reference to one of those ancestors. In that case the key would not violate the BST property, but the back reference should still be detected.